# How to dynamically change NavigateURL string?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, hyperlink, query-string, navigateurl

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="hyp" RunAt="Server" NavigateUrl='<%# "~/URL.aspx?Query=" + DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "QueryID").ToString() %>'>
```

How to replace the **URL.aspx** part of this string in **VB** code behind while maintaining querystring?

**OR**

How to set the querysting in **VB** codebehind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
If (YOUR VARIABLE) = True Then
    hyp.NavigateUrl = "~/URL?Query=" & e.Item.DataItem("SQLDATA").ToString
Else
    hyp.NavigateUrl = "~/URL2.aspx?Query=" & e.Item.DataItem("SQLDATA").ToString
End If
```